# Do I need to include a squared and linear variable in a random forest to achieve a parabolic effect?

Tags: random-forest

I'm using a random forest model. One of my independent variables almost certainly has a parabolic effect on the dependent variable. In a linear regression, I would include the variable as both linear and squared in order to capture this effect. Should I do the same in a random forest?

By extension, same question for variables that have logistic effects (age, for example): should I do the logistic transformation before including it into the random forest?